# Why would lspci not show a particular device?

Tags: motherboard, pci-express

I have a cluster where one of the nodes is not showing a PCI device ([NetFPGA](http://netfpga.org/site/#/systems/1netfpga-sume/details/)).

If I move the NetFPGA to another node, `lspci` shows it.

A different PCI device ([this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NAEU8EG)) *does* show up on the problem node, but not the NetFPGA.

For completeness here is what I've already tried:

- swap motherboard
- swap PSU
- swap NetFPGA into another node (works)
- swap another node's NetFPGA into problem node (does not work)
- try different PCI slots (works with other PCI devices, does not work with NetFPGA)
- update microcode in both CPUs to latest version (same as other nodes in cluster)

The [motherboard](http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon/C600/X10DRW-I.cfm) has 2 Xeons, is it possible that the problem is in one of the processors or its configuration?

Comment: Forgot about this question.  Here is the resolution (if not an answer to the question): After replacing both CPUs, the problem went away. Still not sure of the root cause. Thinking it was either bad microcode, bad CPU, or some combination, in one or both CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

Run lspci -M, that will show all the devices that are missing.  I don't know why lspci does not show all devices, but lspci -M does.

Comment: This does not really answer the author's question.